# Python/Django render enumerated list to table

Tags: python, django

So for a project i'm working on, i want to return data into a table. It is basically this query that gets the data:

```
search_result = sp.search(q=search_query, limit=20)

        response = []
        for i, t in enumerate(search_result['tracks']['items']):
            response += i, t['name']
```

And in the template I try to display the data from the response as follow

```
<tbody>
    {% for data in response %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{data}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Only the data is now being display in a wrong way:

```
------------------------
0
------------------------
[data here]
------------------------
1
------------------------
[data here]
```

I just started programming in python/django, so I am not sure how to display it in a way that the number and data are on the same row, or if I can display it without the integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need that loop in the view. The whole thing should be done in the template. Just send the tracks data directly to the template, and use `forloop.counter`:

```
{% for data in tracks %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td> <td>{{ data }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```